# Alternative to SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I sometimes find SP designer frustrating when I edit web parts, css, etc... as it adds lots of white space which I have to clean up periodically.

Can anyone recommend an alternative, that allows me to edit aspx files, that also shows the code for the web parts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows `mapped network drive` feature. Using this, you can access the SharePoint directory as your normal system folders, and you can edit them using your preferred text editor. Following are the steps you need to follow:

1. Open windows file explorer.
2. From the ribbon click on `Computer` and under network section select `Mapped Network Drive`.
3. In the open dialog box enter select the desired drive letter you want to prefer and for folder provide your site collection URL (e.g. http://abc:1212/sites/team/). If you want to map master page library then use append `_catalogs/masterpage/` in you URL.
4. Check both the check box avaiable i.e. `Reconnect at sign-in` and `Connect using different credentials`.
5. Now Click on `Finish` button. It will ask for credentials, provide the credentials you use to login to site and it all done.

Now you system will show a new Drive, double click it to open the SharePoint directory.

**Open Mapped Network Drive option**
[image: Open Mapped Network Drive]

**New Network drive dialog**
[image: New Network drive dialog.]

**Mapped Network Drive**
[image: Mapped Network Drive]

**SharePoint Directory**
[image: SharePoint Directory]